# I am using React Native Expo everything was working till last month but now i am facing issue while install node-modules

Tags: react-native, expo

i am using
"react-native": "^0.62.2",
"expo": "^38.0.0",
Node Version 14.0.0
Java : 18

All is working good till last month i am facing issue here while install npm so that my build not making on Expo server

Please help me out from this

The error which i am facing now-days is following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 50, in <module>
sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 554, in script_main
return main(sys.argv[1:])
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 547, in main
return gyp_main(args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 520, in gyp_main
[generator, flat_list, targets, data] = Load(
                                        ^^^^^
 File 
 "/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
 gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 136, in Load
 result = gyp.input.Load(build_files, default_variables, includes[:],
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2782, in Load
LoadTargetBuildFile(build_file, data, aux_data,
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 391, in LoadTargetBuildFile
build_file_data = LoadOneBuildFile(build_file_path, data, aux_data,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File 
"/Users/spaculus/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 234, in LoadOneBuildFile
build_file_contents = open(build_file_path, 'rU').read()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU' while trying to load binding.gyp


npm ERR! grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build -- 
library=static_library`
```